# PIC32 external oscillation

Tags: pic

I'm new for PIC32MX and would like to ask the following.
Does the oscillator or resonator generates waves when the micros is not programming i.e. is empty
Tony

Comment: There's no such thing as an "empty" MCU; even an unprogrammed MCU contains opcodes it can potentially execute.

Comment: O'K Ignacio you are right.

Comment: My question is if the pic32mx is not programmed will external oscillator generates waves?

Comment: Does the default unprogrammed memory contents translate into halt opcodes?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I put one unprogrammed pic32m into my pcb and view by oscilloscope if the oscillator (8Mhz) generates waves

Answer (score 1):

According to a [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC32MX_Datasheet_v2_61143B.pdf), the REGISTER 4-7 comes up with all 1's at power-up, which disables the primary oscillator, so the answer should be no, assuming you are referring to the primary oscillator.

Execution proceeds clocked by the internal RC oscillator until/if another clock source is configured. If the flash memory has been erased, that won't happen.